# What is a antonym of 'disaster time' in a formal report?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Is it 'peacetime' or 'ordinary time'?

I need to submit a formal report describing a difference of human behavior in disaster time and ordinary time. What is formal antonym of 'disaster time'?

'Disaster time' means a period right after a large disaster like big earth quake or Tsunami.

BTW, isn't 'disaster time' also formal expression...?

Comment: Perhaps "non-emergency times"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are significantly less [hits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peacetime%2Cdisaster%20time%2C%20ordinary%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeacetime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisaster%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cordinary%20time%3B%2Cc0) for *disaster time* than for peacetime. Organizations that respond to disasters seem to use *[disaster-time](https://books.google.com/books?id=f9tq_Tqlh_oC&pg=PA142&dq=%22disaster%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yknYVPCZCqz-sASJnoHwDQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22disaster%20time%22&f=false)* as a set phrase as the OP indicated. Various organizations refer to the counterpart of disaster as [pre-*disaster*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yTIrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR13&dq=%22disaster%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XIDYVMmDLYmeNuuugtgD&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22disaster%20time%22&f=false) or [*nonemergency*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f9tq_Tqlh_oC&pg=PA142&dq=%22disaster%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XIDYVMmDLYmeNuuugtgD&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22disaster%20time%22&f=false).

---

*[Peacetime](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peacetime)* is an idiomatic expression for what every society longs to be ordinary:

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> A period when a country is not at war:

As the antonym of *disaster-time*, the broader definition of *[peace](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peace)* would need to apply to the compound noun:

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1.0 Freedom from disturbance; *tranquillity*:
>
> *The earthquake terminated a time of peace throughout the city.*
>
> **OED**

[Ordinary Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_Time) is primarily a reference to portions of the Liturgical calendar of organized Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

"normal time" might be suitable.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Well, normal is simply the antonym of disaster.

Answer (score 1):

another word beside normal time is [*typical*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/typical) time or *[ordinary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ordinary)* time: customary; usual; normal.